# How do I find $\lambda$ in the following linear spaces?

Tags: linear-algebra

U and W are two linear spaces of $R^4$:
$\DeclareMathOperator{Span}{Span}$
$$U= \Span \{ (2,2,1,-3), (-\lambda,1-\lambda,-1,4) \}$$
$$W = \Span \{ (1,-2,1,0), (-2,2,0,1) \}$$

How do I calculate the value of $\lambda$ if I know that $\dim(U\cap W) = 1$?

What can I infer from knowing that $\dim(U\cap W) = 1$?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint.**

You have
$$\dim (U+W) = \dim U + \dim W - \dim ( U \cap W).$$
Hence $\dim (U \cap W) = 1$ is only possible if $\dim (U+W) = 3$ as you verify that
$$\dim U = \dim W = 2$$

Finally to have $\dim (U \cap W) = 1$ if and only if the determinant of the 4 vectors vanishes.

Comment: I don't get this sentence "Finally to have $\dim(U∩W)=1$ if and only if the determinant of the 4 vectors vanishes", can you make it more clear to me please

Comment: As I mentioned, you need to have $\dim (U+W) = 3$. If the 4 vectors were linearly independent, you would have $\dim (U+W) = 4$. So they have to be linearly dependent, which means that their determinant vanishes.

Comment: you mean that their determinant is 0?

Comment: Yes the determinant is equal to zero.